# battleship python program to guess correct grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I intend to have my python program run until a blank line is entered, and should work like this:
Guess: C4
Hit C4
Guess: A3
You've chosen that square already
Guess: B2
Hit B2
Guess

---

my code isn't working as intended, it shows error and I can't find a way to make a code to find repeated user input.

```
user_input = input()  

while user_input != "":  
user_input = input ("Guess: ")  

if input == "user_input":  
  print ("You've chosen that square already")  
  break  
else:  
  print ("Hit", user_input)
```

Comment: *it isn't working as intended* is not a meaningful problem statement, and (especially with Python code) you need to properly format and indent your code. Please take some time and [edit] your question to clearly state the problem, include the properly posted code, and ask a *specific* question (*please* isn't one).

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because spacing has meaning in python and your `while` block is improperly indented. Proper spacing goes like this:

```
while user_input != "":  
user_input = input ("Guess: ")  

if input == "user_input":  
  print ("You've chosen that square already")  
  break  
else:  
  print ("Hit", user_input)
```

Of course this won't ever trigger the `if` statement, because `input` isn't an object you've initialized, and certainly doesn't match the string "user_input", but an error-free while statement should be enough to get you started.